# Visual Studio code JS Intellisense of imported Packages not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I am having difficulties in seeing Intellisense for imported JS packages in Visual Studio Code (on Windows).
for example if I `import` a node package like:

```
import toastr from 'toastr';
```

and then i try to use it, no intellisense pops out
[image]

my friend has the same plugins as mine, and it works on his machine.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) file.

`$ npm install -g typings`

`$ typings install toastr --ambient`

You can read more about this in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense-support).

Answer (score 1):

VS Code: v1.24.0
OS: macOS High Sierra

Use `npm install --save-dev @types/name_for_the_ package` to download type declaration files manually will work.

Use the extension [Types auto installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jvitor83.types-autoinstaller) in VS Code to help you download type declaration files when you run npm install.

If your workspace contains more than one project context, you should add a jsconfig.json file.